# Split string by considering multiple values

Tags: python, list, split

I'm trying to split the following type of string in Python 2.7 in order to convert it into a list of values:

```
s = "19, '8X','1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core',342,'4.3', '720x1280','32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, '', 4, 9"
```

I would like to get a list of values similar to:

```
list_s = [19, '8X', '1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core', 342, '4.3', '720x1280', '32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, ' ', 4, 9]
```

I tried to used the function **split()** and the function **re.split()** in the following way:

```
list_s = s.split(",")
#OUTPUT =  ['19', " '8X'", " '1Gb'", " '1.5 GHz dual-core'", ' 342', " '4.3'", " '720x1280'", " '32", '35 x 66', '2 x 10', "12'", ' 130', " ''", ' 4', ' 9']

list_s2 = re.split("([`]|[']|[\"]){1}[,]", s)
#OUTPUT =  ["19, '8X", "'", " '1Gb", "'", " '1.5 GHz dual-core", "'", " 342, '4.3", "'", " '720x1280", "'", " '32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12", "'", " 130, '", "'", ' 4, 9']
```

Can you suggest me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to achieve this using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> s = "19, '8X','1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core',342,'4.3', '720x1280','32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, '', 4, 9"
>>> import ast

>>> ast.literal_eval("[{}]".format(s))
[19, '8X', '1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core', 342, '4.3', '720x1280', '32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, '', 4, 9]
```

Refer ["ast.literal_eval()" document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for more details.

If you are going to use any solution using regex or `str.split()`, then after splitting the elements into strings, you'll have to explicitly type-cast the integers & floats to get your desired list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Direct `eval` for the *fixed*, raw-string works well:

```
>>> s = "19, '8X','1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core',342,'4.3', '720x1280','32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, '', 4, 9"
>>> list(eval(s))
[19, '8X', '1Gb', '1.5 GHz dual-core', 342, '4.3', '720x1280', '32,35 x 66,2 x 10,12', 130, '', 4, 9]
```

However, do look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval). `eval` is certainly dangerous as mentioned in the comments and should be used only on static/fixed raw-strings you are sure about. In that case, the posted answer suggesting `ast.literal_eval` is the safest and correct choice.

Comment: But [eval is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: _Iff_ the string is taken as input (variable, unknown, thus a possibility of being dangerous), in this case, using on a hard-coded string seems fine to me.

Comment: Why even suggest `eval` if it's dangerous, and `literal_eval` works perfectly fine?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!